# Visual Studios Launches Wrong URL With ASP Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an ASP project, and probably will be for a very long time. Which is fine with me because I've fallen in love with MVC, it completely eliminates -most- things I hate about web dev. That said, I has a problem..

So, I right clicked a new index and set it as the start page and now it sends me to..

http://localhost:9240/Views/Home/Index.cshtml

But the URL that works is http://localhost:9240/Home/Index

So when I start the project it 404's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mvc you don't set startup page. To set a default page you can follow below steps.

Right click on your project and go to properties and select start url and write your page url.

[image]

Hope it works

Answer (score 2):

You should not set the start-page on your view file, MVC is not like  web-forms as you start the project it will go to http://localhost:9240/Home/Index by default if you do want to change that you either have to modify your `Action` `Index` to redirect to the action you want in controller or change the default routes.

Comment: Roger that, Thanks Brother.

Comment: Sorry, have to disagree about either changing the default route or setting up the redirect. I have a project that I am building a new section in and to save me time on navigating to that section all the time I simply set the startup location to the URL I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the default route, if you always want to launch from a specific page when debugging, you can set the "Start Action" of your web app by right clicking on the project, go to `Properties -> Web -> Start Action`, check the "Specific Page" radio button, and input the URL you wish to land on.

This can be helpful if you're working on a particular feature in a large web application, and you want to save yourself a few clicks every time you go to debug.

MSDN for reference : [Change the Start Action for Application Debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68c8335t(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the headsup, I'll look into it.